# How to restrict a generic type of a method to an object in typescript?

Tags: typescript, react-hooks, typescript-generics

I have been trying to come up with a generic type to my method and restrict that type to an object with following requirements.

Below is the function I'm working with. However this function is used within a custom hook in React app.

```js
function useCustomHook<T>(initialData: T[]) {
  const [changes, setChanges] = React.useState<T[]>([])

  // calling the method inside the hook with an element should be retrieved from changes
  doSomething() 
}

function doSomething<T>(obj: T) {
  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    console.log(key, value)
  })
}

// Type
type ExampleType = {
  property1: number,
  property2: string
}
// Interface
interface ExampleInterface {
  property1: number;
  property2: string;
}
```

It should throw an error for the following examples (basically it should not accept any primitive type such as string, number, boolean, null, undefined, ...):

```js
doSomething('test')
doSomething(12)
doSomething(undefined)
```

And it should accept the following examples:

```js
doSomething({})
doSomething({ property1: 12, property2: 'string'})


doSomething<ExampleType>({ property1: 12, property2: 'string'})
doSomething<ExampleInterface>({property1: 12, property2: 'string'})
```

I have already tried to change the method like so:
function doSomething<T **extends Record<string, unknown>**>

It works for most the examples (meaning it throws an error) but it does not work when an interface is used (throws Index signature is missing). Changing existing interfaces to types is not a solution and I think if the example function was a part of library I as the user of the library would like to have both the options - interface and type.

However it works if I change unknown to any but I believe using any should be avoided in Typescript.

I would appreciate any advice. I believe there's got to be a way to achieve it. Here is the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-wildflower-hqr1t

Answer (score 3):

The right thing to do here is to [constrain](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) the type parameter `T` to [the `object` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-2.html#object-type), which specifically means "a type which is not a primitive":

```
function doSomething<T extends object>(obj: T) {
  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    console.log(key, value)
  })
}
```

And you can verify that it works that way:

```
doSomething('test'); // error
doSomething(12); // error
doSomething(undefined); // error
doSomething({}) // okay
doSomething({ property1: 12, property2: 'string'}) // okay
doSomething<ExampleType>({ property1: 12, property2: 'string'}) // okay
doSomething<ExampleInterface>({property1: 12, property2: 'string'}) // okay
```

This is exactly what the `object` type was meant to do in TypeScript, and why it exists.

---

Now, at this point I expect the response that when you use [ESLint's `ban-types` rule](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/bbbef82df5a488fd5d5128c9ab47dc5af07d08e5/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/ban-types.md) with the default configuration, it complains about `object` with a warning of the form:

> Avoid the `object` type, as it is currently hard to use due to not being able to assert that keys exist. See [microsoft/TypeScript#21732](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21732).

This rule might be well-meaning and useful in situations, and `object` does have some drawbacks, but as you've seen, `Record<string, unknown>` is not always an improvement.  That something is "hard to use" presumably doesn't mean that it should be completely banned in favor of something else, especially if that something else doesn't work for the use case.  It's hard to use a knife to open a can, and you should probably use a can opener instead, but that doesn't mean you should try to slice your bread with a can opener.  Different types have different use cases.  And `T extends object` in the above code seems to be 100% the right tool for this job.

I might be a little over-emotional about this issue since I was the person who filed [microsoft/TypeScript#21732](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21732), and I would love to see `key in obj` act as a type guard on `obj` that asserts property existence.  But [that issue absolutely does not mean that `object` is useless](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21732#issuecomment-886221640), and it's a bit exhausting to see all those GitHub issues in other projects linking to this as the reason why they carefully excised `object` from their code.

Oh well!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.3#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEzgZTgWwKZQBYxgDmAPACqLYAeU2YyAzonAEYBW20AfABStsAuRGQCUiAN4AoRIgDy7TlAB0dKACcY2Bn3YilwOGoCiAQwh4ePANoBrbAE8ANIgBuJgDYhsAXTEBeLglpGUQIBAY4d2wldzgiHjsnVw8vEWCAXzT0yUkAelzhewAHbEkoYuxEIyoTTCKosgrEPyCZIrU4ErVygEYhMBBMFmw1R2D2zpHygCYhBnVCIkls-MQASTBaNWAzUsItnYhK6tr67A2D3dbECa7e-sHhtQBucY67+1nEeY1iV+zJKgMDh8IseAByWjzcEiZ6IVYjDpqQHoLC4AjEHg9aaw+EFRGGFHA9Fg8DIbDAQjYZC4hFqJFEtGgzHiTJ45g2Ez2RkgjHxcQ3d5Tex9RDY5y3YVfcE-RbgtmrOCc7lApl8kgnOoNCq8AWS7oioTiwWTA3S2XEeViRXKnkk4gampa86bEaHbC6-X3MXTCVCs1CGULS0KgpKrmSIA)

Comment: I think you just convinced me to lift this rule in my codebase. It's not like we're talking about `any` here. Also one missed case here, which is not sure is required for the OP's use case, is an array.

Comment: An array isn't a primitive, so I'm not sure why we'd want to exclude it (although iterating through arrays as if they were plain objects sometimes does strange things).

Answer (score 0):

I offer this answer with the caveat that, sadly, I'm not 100% sure why this works.

But if you leave the generic unconstrained and make the argument type:

```
T & Record<string, unknown>
```

Then it works as you expect.

```
function doSomething<T>(obj: T & Record<string, unknown>) {
  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    console.log(key, value)
  })
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictPropertyInitialization=false&ssl=1&ssc=34&pln=1&pc=57#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEzgZTgWwKZQBYxgDmAPACoB8AFHAEYBWAXImYgGSIBK2EcATshIBnKH0JEANInABrMHADuYCgEpEAbwCwAKESIA8gx5QAdNjCiY2ITQYqTwfgFEAhhDxUqAbRnYAnlIAbi4ANiDYALpqALwUGjp6erxgQnAh2CYhcERUvgGIwWHYKgmIAL4l2mU6OgD0tSx+AA7YOlDN2IhOAB4umE3pZB2I0fG6iE18cC187QCMzGAgmLTYfBKlk9Nr7QBMzCJixDrV2vWIAJIWa8BurdqEUDd3Xb396VdPfLcQnVrjWxm80Wy1WfAA3JspkC-PtEIdxJCqjUzg0nHwpnwhIgXNjsN0WtBsMhGDpUBgcPhxFQAORPEQ0yrkrC4AjEKhzXZM9Asqns8DIbDAQjE7kU1nU24hITFMk8ylsnJeKIouoNADq-Bk2NxiHxhKeyDl4r5OXUFWNvMVVHUE2hOz8C0QnKkgIdcJpCOINIt2mZCvEJB6fQG2CGLWotrds0dzBddu2MY9XqIPrFVsDwfe2E+z1+kejwOdu1d9qTzE9lm9FSAA)

---

Hypothesis:

When you infer a generic parameter it must full satisfy that constraint. In this case `Record` implies an index signature which doesn't exist in the `interface`. `T` must be assignable to `Record<string, unknown>`. But it is not.

However, when you type the argument as `T & Record<string, unknown>` you tell Typescript that `T` can be anything but the argument is only allowed if whatever `T` is has string keys. If it does not, the type resovles to `never` and nothing is assignable to `never`.

At least I think. But to be honest I'm not completely solid on all semantics of `type` vs `interface` here.

---

Or another approach would be to explicitly blacklist all the primitive values with something like:

```
type NotPrimitive<T> =
   T extends string | boolean | number | null | undefined | unknown[]
    ? never
    : T

function doSomething<T>(obj: NotPrimitive<T>) {
  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    console.log(key, value)
  })
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictPropertyInitialization=false&ssl=10&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAcg9sACgJwJYFtXFQNwgHgBUA+KAXgFgAoKWwqCAD2AgDsATAZyk+DVYDmUAD5QARnDgAbCAENWIqKwCu6MRGSKVUqYuUcIAM1SsI7PawDWrOAHdWAbQC61WrQD8SiHmSu3ALihCampDfQBjbDgFdjgAZTh0CGAACxMBImIACjgxACtA+CQ0TGw8TIBKKABvPwB5fIhIgDo2PlQIThz8iubDOGQAUVlwlKysh0sIEAAaKBxZKWUIJyqyUlqaN3DozmkIZqk4ASyp2fnF5Yq-AF9rqhuQqgB6Z6DwCGpQSChBxll0GAZIQPuQan4wMg4JBkKAAIyBFRqDQzCFQmGgABMgV4-AE1EeLzeAElWCxkIYRp8qCZyZTwtA-gCgRBSXSqeCtpDoRp4YjVOpkABuNE82EgbE8dqCEUPJ6vX7IKHIbiybhMSCRMz+aixBJJVLpLIAchYvGN9z1iWSaUEWThmMt8Wthrt+nYRhMZid+ptRspUk4EB9LttJ2c93lbwA6gNLKr1YxNSx2LrnQaw1lqnc077XSdqlBuRiQAioA65sXeRLAsbceljTmqFaM+l8EzAcCPtlC1XxWWK0X0dXJXXpQJGyHW4J2-9O6yyRp6RAe32+eXMZXh+LR-XBJOgA)

Comment: Thanks Alex. However I don't think I can change the type of the parameter. I added further details to the question. I apologise it was not 100% complete.

Comment: Your edit doesn't really help explain things. You aren't passing anything to the function in your example. But I've updated my answer with an alternative that might work better.

Comment: Leaving this here because I do think it's useful, but @jcalz has the far better answer.